# How to rsync files with filename number bigger than a number?

Tags: files, find, rsync, wildcards

I got a few hundred folders, all with the same name structure, ##** , I need to backup with rsync all the folders within 00* to 15_ range to a drive and 16_ to 99_ to another drive. How can I filter the each list to pass this to rsync?.

```
drwxrwxrwx+  10 user  user    4096 Feb 16  2017 07_MrSmith
drwxrwxrwx+   3 user  user    4096 Mar 24 12:55 10_Other_File
drwxrwxrwx+   4 user  user    4096 Aug 23 14:33 15_New_Interesting_folder
drwxrwxrwx+   9 user  user    4096 Aug 31 17:23 16_SimpleFolderNaming
drwxrwxrwx+   3 user  user    4096 May  8 12:53 17_VeryCurious
drwxrwxrwx+   6 user  user    4096 Mar 28 12:38 17_MantinanVinil
drwxrwxrwx+   3 user  user    4096 Mar 28 11:47 17_AnotherFolderWith_Subfolders
```

I tried looking for parameters of the 'find', 'xargs' or 'rsync' command that allows to compare subsets with numbers, but I can't find a solution to this.

When I do:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '..[0-1][0-5]_*'
```

to filter the folders within 00-15 range doesn't returns anything.

Comment: `_*` is 0 or more underscores. ITYM, `_.*` (underscore followed by 0 or more characters). `[0-1][0-5]` doesn't match on `06`

Comment: Thank you!, I don't know how I missed that one. Now I'll look into passing this list to rsync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
rsync ... <0-15>_*(/) somewhere
rsync ... <16->_*(/) somewhere-else
```

With `ksh` or `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob`:

```
rsync ... @(0[0-9]|1[0-5])_* somewhere
rsync ... @(1[6-9]|[2-9][0-9])_* somewhere-else
```

Or you could do it in separate globs (though you'll see error messages from `rsync` if either of the glob doesn't match any file and you could end-up rsyncing files that are called literally `0[0-9]_*`, `1[0-5]_*`...):

```
rsync ... 0[0-9]_* 1[0-5]_* somewhere
rsync ... 1[6-9]_* [2-9][0-9]_* somewhere-else
```

(note that `bash` and `ksh` don't support the `(/)` glob qualifier to select files of type directory only).

POSIXly:

```
find . ! -name . -prune \( -name '0[0-9]_*' -o -name '1[0-5]_*' \) \
  -type d -exec sh -c 'exec rsync ... "$@" somewhere' sh {} +
find . ! -name . -prune \( -name '1[6-9]_*' -o -name '[2-9][0-9]_*' \) \
  -type d -exec sh -c 'exec rsync ... "$@" somewhere-else' sh {} +
```